# Connection to Azure database

Tags: c#, sql, azure

I'm yust started to learn with Windows Azure, now I want to test to write something to a SQL database. I tried to connect with my own build connection settings what I used to connect to the SQL server, but it faild. So I took the tutorial from the [azure site](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-dotnet-how-to-use/) well I couldn't get a connection. Now I found [this site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ee336243.aspx) but still no connection. '

When I look on my dashboard in the Azure Portal I see that Azure has noticed 14 succesfull connections. So I think something went wrong on my end?

Error:

> "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

Comment: What do you mean `it faild`? Show your code. Do you get a compile error? Runtime exception? If so, what are they? Or do you get unexpected behavior? Something else? Please specify.

Comment: I added enough code I think, and when you read the text I wrote that I already have a working connection to a SQL server, I used this to connect to the Azure database, but there the connection failed...But added the errorcode :)

Answer (score 0):

Open your db dashboard. There is a menu at the right side on the page. Check  Manage allowed IP addresses. Perhaps, you have to add allowed IP range to allow access.
Hope this helps.

Comment: When I set up the database, I got the warning, so I had already accepted this IP adres, I will check to set a range

Comment: Well, what is the error? And do you use connection strings which is provided by Azure? (you can see them at your dashboard)

Comment: I added the error tought I did it earlyer, but yes I have tried the connection string provided, than I used the articles mentioned earlyer

Comment: Try to connect using Management Studio. I bet that the DB might be down. If Management Studio connects, then the problem in your code. If it doesn't, then MS Azure has some temporary problems.

Answer (score 0):

I need to check the network at my work, I'm at home and I try to connect, without any problem.
Thanks voor each thinking of you :)